# how can I test view where authentication is required, with cakePHP and SimpleTest

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, simpletest

I'd like to write WebTestCase of views that requires authentification. Is it possible? How can I pass authentification?

I tried with writing basic authentification in the session but it doesn't work.

```
    $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['username'] = 'nico';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function login() {
        $this->get($this->host_name."/users/login/");
        $this->assertText("Login");
        $this->setField("data[User][username]",'xxxx');
        $this->setField("data[User][password]",'xxxx');
        $this->assertClickable("login");
        $this->clickSubmit("login");
        $this->assertNoText("Error:");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. When one sees the solution it looks so obvious. Web testing is to test from user point of view. I'm new to testing, I don't have the good relexes.